# Unable to import single-spa utility module into Vite (Vue) micro-frontend

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, single-spa

I have a project built with single-spa, Micro-frontend modules are Vue-js (created with vue-cli), and a utility module containing some api calls.

I am trying to migrate the my Vue vue-cli microfrontends to Vite, migration was successfull except for importing the utility module: It's a module built using webpack and served as an In-Browser module.

When I import the utility module I am facing this issue:

```
[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve entry for package "@project/example-api". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
```

**vite.config.ts for Micro-Frontend:**

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [`@project/example-api`],
      input: `src/main.ts`,
      output: {
        assetFileNames: `js/app.[ext]`,
        chunkFileNames: `js/app.js`,
        entryFileNames: `js/app.js`,
        format: `system`,
        globals: {
          '@project/example-api': `@project/example-api`,
        },
      },
      preserveEntrySignatures: `strict`,
    },
    ssr: false,
  },
  plugins: [vue({
    template: {
      transformAssetUrls: {
        base: `/src`,
      },
    },
  })],
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [`@project/example-api`],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: `@`,
        replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL(`./src`, import.meta.url)),
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

tried to make an allias for the Utility module, as a 'remote served version' but I had a different kind of error:

```
{
    find: `@project/example-api`,
    replacement: http://example.com/mfe/example-api/example-api.js`,
},
```

**Error message:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: application '@project/navbar-mfe' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: The requested module 'http://example.com/mfe/example-api/example-api.js' does not provide an export named 'myApi' (at App.vue:19:12)
```

**In root config, I have this import statements:**

```
......
<script>
    System.import('@project/root-config');
    System.import("@project/example-api");
</script>
......
```

**Utility module webpack.config.js:**

```
const { merge } = require(`webpack-merge`);
const singleSpaDefaults = require(`webpack-config-single-spa-ts`);

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName: `project`,
    projectName: `example-api`,
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
    disableHtmlGeneration: true,
  });

  const deployTarget = webpackConfigEnv?.deployTarget ? `.${webpackConfigEnv.deployTarget.toLowerCase().trim()}` : `.dev`;
  const inputCopyConfigPattern = {
    from: `src/config/config${deployTarget}.json`,
    to: `src/config/config.json`,
  };

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    // ....
  });
};
```

Is there a possibilty (different way) to import an external JS module built with webpack into ViteJS? specifically if it is bundled in system format, served separately and imported via system.import in single-spa root-config index?

Comment: Did you add the import map for `@project/example-api`?  It looks like this is what you're missing.